# size read failed - SASLAUTHD with PAM_MYSQL Fedora 38 /same Fedora 35/

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-38

I am using Fedora long time and installed maybe 10mail servers with PAM_MYSQL authentication over SASLauthd

I wanted to make new server on new Fedora 37, same as before. But without success of usage SASL with PAM_mysql

Users are crypted in DB via postfixadmin in MD5CRYPT and password encrypted in MD5RAW as default setting

Dovecot which is not using PAM_mysql is working only PAM_mysql

in SASL with PAM_MYSQL - everytime when user exists, it writes me "size read failed" and SASL deactivate it

There is visible in Journalctl that problem looks be in PAM_MYSQL
see file [journal](https://shop5.wifiprofi.cz/error_journal.txt)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVEJn.jpg)

I am expecting same behaviour as in older versions, where SASL worked well /e.g. I have Fedora 26 with older SASL cyrus-sasl-2.1.26-32.fc26.x86_64 with no problems/

in new not working versions, sometimes I have "OK.Success" but after few tries "size read failed"

I am using command "testsaslauthd -u klima@wifiprofi.cz -p test -s smtp"
user and password is in SQL table mailbox